# Public key PEM-like created in c is not accepted in php.Both have openssl

Tags: php, c, openssl, key, public

**Create public key OpenSSL in c**

```
  RSA *rsaKeyPair;
        rsaKeyPair = RSA_new();
        BIGNUM* exp = NULL;
        exp = BN_new();
        BN_set_word(exp, 65537);
        RSA_generate_key_ex(rsaKeyPair, 2048, exp, NULL);
         /* To get the C-string PEM form: */
   PEM_write_bio_RSAPublicKey(bio, rsaKeyPair);
   keylen = BIO_pending(bio);
   pem_key = calloc(keylen+1, 1); /* Null-terminate */
   BIO_read(bio, pem_key, keylen);
   printf("%s", pem_key);        // public key
```

**Then copy-paste in php code.**

```
$key2 = <<<EOT
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBCgKCAQEAn9VPzLkhDIzPZCA3rYEOttipOjokVQjN7XUjN++n+aYM8PNYp9QY
zlllawj16WE7KchiHjAng5Z+/wgNuz6uxRT4rYcQdjQ+l6JgayVv17vmc4gjuvqN
HeI1vJzs6Ob/kRLRf+QqX84zbSaIWjV1mtVBAyYfG0ln2JW3QvOueGLSV79s0lpE
08YRdXDZ7ohkEWa266RZ5w4970ALVHod8Mq8yPWvQFDpVT7UCMt1Apkz8VfF0zzz
1pxe2NWBJSnuhOkJ3Za+MG1SbiqmHpk6a+wvH9oJYyuR0PV6Tj0baVWenYDY+a6X
m4lmZM18IeLE7RZIqUlfY42hgkviJ45zpQIDAQAB
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
EOT;
openssl_public_encrypt($c,$d,$key2);
```

**Error is**

*Warning: openssl_public_encrypt(): key parameter is not a valid public key*

Have tried with base64encode in c and decode in php, send over url. Didn't help. Key in 2 ways looks the same.

Here is working locally created public key in php

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAyIZzbuW0B7LNQR5JKqCD 6gRKp3DvRkZISaAQDQACSaOpIq7zRUVkgdrYXniECXBmzwGc3Fu5ECkvP0SWbaCI MBh0/YkPKbiQuAnhRwtcVQ8gFKaJ2vdUwp44PkP5pVvfraJPGmfWPAfiL9PyZmRN 1uZfgPznsNVrxqwZvYhApJy57vn4YL4J7kHpK3Peb/K4yTCMyAV/CE8YIe9q0p+L rzFQyIQm2dZ/OI7IU0izQwkbV0ZoMuUGJLhiPMrJ/dkOP3cDLdepJBewald2Hdnp 1aROlXhw0zp4Pj2ERgKkvJ+FnLJ0Se9XxGBBt4e+6gioQfdxvNwKk1oWmsIiyaRE UwIDAQAB -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Comment: PEM_write_bio_RSA_PUBKEY() gives standart format. While PEM_write_bio_RSAPublicKey()  is not along with standart.